# Headless Linux - skip as many boot errors as possible

Tags: boot

I'm using headless Linux server. When changing some system stuff over SSH I have always fear if everything will be ok at the boot time. 
For example - yesterday I forgot one option in mount (fstab file) and it hangs at the boot time (because it doesn't have the network at the moment!). You can imagine how it looks. The computer on other location, without monitor and keyboard and there will be only (press S for continue). 
Is there any option to tell Linux that it should skip as many errors as possible?

Comment: What was the line in fstab (and what distro and version)? I'd have thought Linux would try to continue - possibly after a delay - if possible - but I guess it depends on the distro and also if its using systemd. In some cases it may be possible to change the system boot order to bring up a more usable system in case of failures - but mounting happens fairly early on.

Comment: This was just an example from yesterday. It was Debian on Raspberry PI, where I try with WebDAV to cloud storage. I forgot _netdev options and Raspberry didn't start. Take a car, monitor, keyboard ... and go on a way :-)
But never mind, I just thought if there is some boot option which won't stop at an error, but will wait some time and then goes on (until success or heavy error).